# Java Design - Singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I have following design requirements:

- `interface Server {}`
- `public class ServerImpl implements Server {}`, must be a Singleton
- `public class ServerABC extends ServerImpl {}`
- `public class ServerXYZ extends ServerImpl {}`

Now I want to put methods in class `Server` their implementation should be given by either `ServerABC` or `ServerXYZ`.

In `ServerImpl`

```
public class ServerImpl implements Server {
    private static Server server;

    public static synchronized RESTClient getInstance() {
        if (server == null) {
            server = new ServerImpl ();
        }
        return server;
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

If I put methods in `Server` interface, `ServerImpl` has to implement it but I want the subclasses (`ServerABC` and `ServerXYZ`) to provide implementation. These methods should be called using ServerImpl object.

Comment: *Why* do you want it to be a singleton? The singleton design pattern is almost always a bad idea. It makes testing harder and generally has all the normal problems of global state.

Comment: Need only one instance of Server in JVM.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons and google "Singletons are evil"

Comment: @user958263: just because you only need one instance does not automatically mean it has to be a singleton - most of the time it's much better to make your class a normal non-singleton class, then just instantiate it only once.

Comment: I think it's only a student task.

Comment: That's just restating it, not justifying it. Why don't you just ensure *by the way you configure your server* that you end up with one instance?

Comment: I cannot understand this use case: you want a single instance of ServerImpl but you never use it because you actually use ServerABC and ServerXYZ which provide the actual implementations? Why do you need an instance of ServerImpl in the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider that the best way is to avoid the Singleton pattern. If you only need one instance, then create just one instance. Singleton is been known to make testing more difficult and doesn't really bring a huge benefit.

What I would do in your situation is:

- either eliminate the interface and make the class `ServerImpl` an abstract class. All the  methods that should be implemented in a subclass must be marked abstract as well. There are cases where you want that only one of the subclasses to provide an implementation for a specific method. In this case, just throw an [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) in the classes that must not implement it. **OR**
- eliminate the class `ServerImpl` and simply have the 2 other classes implement the interface. If the class `ServerImpl` doesn't implement much on its own, then this is the better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Make `Server` interface an abstract class, and prefix the methods with `abstract` keyword. Then, in the `ServerImpl` you implement those abstract methods.

### EDIT:

Make `ServerImpl` an abstract class, and prefix those methods with `abstract` keyword. And in `ServerABC` and `ServerXYZ` you implement these abstract methods.

Comment: I dont want ServerImpl to provide implementation. I want ServerABC and ServerXYZ to provide implementation

Answer (score 0):

Create a abstract class named AbstractServer . Put all you necessary methods in this class and extend it in ServerXYZ and ServerABC .

Comment: I also want AbstractServer to implement **Server** interface and it should be singleton